# Exclude plugins on Main site on Multisite installation?

Tags: plugins, multisite

I am using wordpress Multisite installation .

1)I want to run my website faster .Especially the main site.There are near about 50 plugins .I want to exclude many of these plugins on Main site and activate to other sub-sites.Could any body tell me how to do it?

I have other three questions related to plugins on multisite installation:

2)Is there any chance for too much load on server or trouble loading pages if I Use 50 + plugins?

3)For two months I installed many plugins and un-installed them .Now i doubt that if the traces of these deleted plugins affect the server load. Is that true? If so how can I get rid of them ?

4)Some of the plugins would be activated on some sub-sites and active on some other sub-sites.So does the plugins on the sub-sites which are not active affect the server load?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: I don't think so. Inactive plugins shouldn't slow down the site

Comment: Is it a good Idea to get started with a fresh installation deleting the present one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I only recently started to poke multisite, as far as I understand you activate plugins per-site by activating theme in that site's admin area. You can switch between backend of different sites in `Super Admin > Sites > (hover cursor on site) > Backend`.
2. Server load is not about quantity of plugins, but quality and performance specific of plugins used, amount of page views and caching.
3. You can try plugin like [Clean Options](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/clean-options/) to check for leftover settings, but it is still manual work to properly determine and safely remove options. Leftover database tables are even more of a mess.
4. Inactive plugins are not processed in any way. WordPress stores information about active plugins in database and only loads those on the list. Rest are merely ignored files on hard drive when inactive.

Comment: >1)I  need The pluginsto be active on Main site .They should be activated site wide except on multisite.

2)How do I know if a plugin functions abnormally ?

        Thanks !

Comment: @user391 (1) not sure about mechanics, I _think_ plugins are not site-wide by default unless they are dropped in mandatory plugins folder. (2) without preliminary testing - you don't until it causes issues. Try to stick to minimum amount of popular and well maintained plugins.

Comment: Is it a good Idea to get started with a fresh installation deleting the present one?

Answer (score 2):

If your server load is high, it could be due to all kinds of factors. As for plugins, there's no magic number, but inactive plugins do not add any load.

If your site is being visited a lot, that has more to do with load that anything. Or a wonky plugin. An incorreclty coded plugin can do more damage than ten perfect ones.

Comment: I'd give WPML as a example here :) It increases database queries 10 times